# How to create boolean expression in javascript and generate a message using alert()?

Tags: javascript, boolean, alert, prompt

I am writing a program in JavaScript that tells user if they have won in the competition or not. 
The conditions are: Girl’s record is 20 seconds, boys’ record is 15 seconds
false start is anything  less than 0.50 seconds, if a contestant  has a false start then they have not won.
I have to use the  prompt() command to ask if they are competing in the boys’s or girls’, then ask for their score, and reaction time. Write a Boolean expression and create a message with alert()command telling them if they have  won or not.
When asking which event the user is competing in, acceptable answers are 
“boys” or “girls” .  So far I have this, but I don’t think it is entirely right.

```
var boysRecord = 15;
var girlsRecord = 20;
var falseStart = 0. 50;
var event = prompt("Are you competing in the boys or girls event?");
if (event == "boys" || "girls");
var score = prompt("What is your score?");
 } else {
var event = prompt("Are you competing in the boys or girls event?");
var reactionTime = prompt("What is your reaction time?");
if 
 (event == "boys"; && score > 15; && reactionTime >= 0.5);
{ alert(" You have won");
} else if {
(event = "girls"; && score > 20; && reactionTime >= 0.5);
{ alert(" You have won");
}
else {
    alert(" You have lost");
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you think is wrong? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: logically wouldn't they *win* if their score was less than 15 and 20 respectively?

Comment: 15 and 20 are previous records, so one would need to achieve higher score than this to win.

Comment: I was assuming this was an **event** such as the the 100 meter dash since it has both **boys and girls** who  **compete** to get the lowest time in **seconds** in which a **false start** results in a competitor **losing**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend you indent your code. It's easier to read and helps you keep track of the brackets.

You have a few errors. You are missing some brackets and have too much semicolons.

Here's the code that should work:

```
var boysRecord = 15;
var girlsRecord = 20;
var falseStart = 0.50;
var event = prompt("Are you competing in the boys or girls event?");
if (event == "boys" || "girls"){
    var score = prompt("What is your score?");
} else {
    event = prompt("Are you competing in the boys or girls event?")
}
var reactionTime = prompt("What is your reaction time?");
if(event == "boys" && score > 15 && reactionTime >= 0.5){
    alert(" You have won");
} else if(event = "girls" && score > 20 && reactionTime >= 0.5){
    alert(" You have won");
} else {
    alert(" You have lost");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Carlos mentioned your code is mess.

I guess you are trying to do something like this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/wpjuzjae/8/

Note: Before writing your second line make sure your first line works. Copy pasting block of code does not work always.

Good luck

```
var boysRecord = 15;
var girlsRecord = 20;
var falseStart = 0.50;
var score = 0;
var event = prompt("Are you competing in the boys or girls event?");
while (event != "boys" && event != "girls") {
  event = prompt("Are you competing in the boys or girls event?");
}

var score = prompt("What is your score?");
var reactionTime = prompt("What is your reaction time?");

if (event == "boys" && score > 15 && reactionTime >= 0.5) {
  alert(" You have won");
} else if (event = "girls" && score > 20 && reactionTime >= 0.5) {
  alert(" You have won");
} else {
  alert(" You have lost");
}
```